# All files of android project got corrupted

Tags: android, android-studio, file-recovery, corrupt-data

When I opened my previous android project on android studio after 15 days. I found that files had been corrupted.There was only a message that "File was loaded in wrong encoding - 'UTF-8'". Is it possible to recover the project files?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: your previous project was on studio or eclipse?

Comment: On the same system ,same android studio @Tej

Comment: Are you using Windows and it has crashed previously? Then say goodbye to your code. I've experienced the same problem months ago and losing 2 weeks of codes because of it. Moral of the story: always backup your code with Version control systems.

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך Yes I am working on window 10 but It haven't crashed yet. I am also wondering why my code has got corrupt. One of the interesting thing only this project got corrupted  others are safe

Comment: Well, it's because Windows 10 filesystem is not reliable. You can try to fix it using `chkdsk` command. But please backup your data first.

Comment: Are you using a version control system?

Comment: is it really an unanswerable question?

Answer (score 2):

**no need for any setting just use following step**

> 1. close project
> 2. rename project root folder name
> 3. re-open project from new name (changeable folder name)

Comment: Please check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153703/file-was-loaded-in-the-wrong-encodingutf-8-in-intellij-idea

Comment: This worked. But why does this happen ? Is it the problem with Windows 10 OS or Android studio problem ?

Comment: this problam main resone is iinterrupted electrycity or interrupted Android studio

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Settings -> File Types.
Find the file type that you have linked the .ttf files to

Deactivate it with the red minus sign on the right hand side.
The next time you'll try to import a .ttf file in Android Studios there will be a popup menu where:

You can select Android Studios to read the .ttf files as a certain filetype
You can select the program that normally reads .ttf on your computer (The button on the bottom of the menu).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have not found such an option "supress for class" @Anubis

Comment: It didn't help me