# IDEA File was loaded in the wrong encoding:'UTF-8'

Tags: intellij-idea

When I open IDEA with a project, which includes tomact, I meet the messy code, as follow:

[image]

When I reload coding scheme with UTF-8, the problem still exists. I search for this way: [File was loaded in the wrong encoding:'UTF-8' in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153703/file-was-loaded-in-the-wrong-encodingutf-8-in-intellij-idea?newreg=d76e1f7506ff403dbdedb3af643fbf3d)

However, it is still not effective.

Comment: It looks like the code of this .java file is corrupted. What is shown on your screenshot is not a file loaded in a wrong encoding, it's just garbage.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Close the IDE.
2. Deleted this directory
3. Run the IDE again.

That's my way... and hope it could help someone.