# Save Array List to Text file

Tags: java, android

I've spent all day on this and need some advice!

I'm trying to save the contents of a Array List into a text file.

I have got android to save the array list contents to an internal *.txt however after entering "Test one" and "Test Two" into the array list, and a button is clicked to save the current contents into the text file. I get the following:

```
�� sr java.util.ArrayListx����a� I sizexp   w   t Test Onet Test Twox
```

An Error is also given which is:

```
 "File was loaded in the wrong encoding:'UTF-8'
```

The `System.out.print` gives the results:

```
 "I/System.out: [Test One, Test Two]"
```

which is accurate to show the contents of the array list.

Code used:

```
public void savingfile() {
    read = (Button)findViewById(R.id.read);
    read.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {

                outputStream = openFileOutput(anxfile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);

                out.writeObject(arrayList);

                System.out.println(arrayList);

                outputStream.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Many thanks, Leon
P.S. I have tried many youtube tutorials/Stackoverflow answers to fix the problem but still having the same issue

Comment: Try this,  might work https://stackoverflow.com/a/47396757/1004631

Comment: You are writing it out with an `ObjectOutputStream`, therefore it is serialized. You can easily read it again with an `ObjectInputStream`.

But because you insist to using a `.txt` file, and somehow try to read it with utf-8 encoding (which will fail, because the java serialization format is a binary format), I believe you want just the `String`s in the `ArrayList` printed to the file. In that case, what you you want to do with it? What format do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The list contains Strings, right?

If so, then instead of writing the object into your stream:
    `out.writeObject(arrayList);`

You may want to dig out the Strings from the List first and write them:

```
for (String text : arrayList) {
    out.writeObject(text);
}
```

Comment: Hei, that doesn't matter! You can write an arraylist directly as well!