# File was loaded in wrong encoding: UTF-8

Tags: java, android-studio

I have been working on a project for over six months now when after an Android Studio upgrade, some of my files open with the error "File was loaded in wrong encoding: UTF-8".

POSSIBLE DUPLICATE:

In my case Android Studio does not show the wrong file contents, as in text from another file or from somewhere else, it shows the wrong encoding. I found a bug on the Google Issue Tracker that explains my problem. [Google Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120435934). Have a look at the images attached to the bug for a clear explanation.

Comment: Let me guess: You haven't found [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153703/file-was-loaded-in-the-wrong-encodingutf-8-in-intellij-idea), have you? (Android Studio is based on IntelliJ IDEA).

Comment: Similar question was asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153703/file-was-loaded-in-the-wrong-encodingutf-8-in-intellij-idea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File was loaded in the wrong encoding:'UTF-8' in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153703/file-was-loaded-in-the-wrong-encodingutf-8-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Comment: @deHaar I did find the question. However, my project is not opened over the network nor is it an Eclipse project. The question you are referring to is unanswered.

Comment: @MangaldeepPannu Please refer to my response to deHaar

Comment: @Hendré the question is answered, but none of the answers is accepted. OK, if your question is not related to the one I linked, then sorry. I just wanted to provide something related...

Comment: @Zoe Please refer to my revised question under POSSIBLE DUPLICATE.

Comment: You still have no example of what the problem is, nor do you specify what you've tried. Wrong file content is usually accompanied by wrong encoding, so I took a guess in the blanks of the information. I didn't see the dupe deHaar posted, but as far as I see, there's two close reasons: duplicate and unclear. I'll leave my vote, which it's closed as a dupe of is up to the rest of the closers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue was resolved when I downgraded my Android Studio from version 3.3.2 down to 3.3.0.