# Android Studio "File was loaded in the wrong encoding:'UTF-8'" and "Java file does not declare any class" out of nowhere

Tags: android, android-studio, file-encodings

Please note that I've read "[File was loaded in the wrong encoding:'UTF-8' in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153703/file-was-loaded-in-the-wrong-encodingutf-8-in-intellij-idea)" this, and everything else related to this issue that I'm having which is going to make me rewrite everything that I did in my project in past 2 days.

Now, the only reason I'm asking this question, is because if someone else faces this problem in future, it'd possibly have a solution by then?

**So here is the problem**:

I was working on my app which is already present on Play Store, I made all the changes in code, and wanted to add stuff in old java file. But, I was suddenly greeted with this beautiful thing:

[image: Error in Android Studio]

Now, the error first said `"File was loaded in the wrong encoding UTF-8"` and gave me bunch of options to change my encoding. Now, as a programmer, I know if I have any issues, I should Google them, and found all the answers related to this issue, and I tried all those, **fortunately**, after trying all those answers, above error was gone, and only one "warning(?)" remained saying `"Java file does not declare any class"`. Now, the amazing part is, if it was encoding error from Android Studios Code editor, it should have been totally fine if I opened it in another text editor right? I opened it using "Brackets" & also "Notepad", but I was again greeted with this beautiful thing:

[image: Screenshot of Brackets Text Editor]

Now, I'm totally clueless as to where I went wrong here, as some classes are working fine (most of those are `Activities`), but a lot of them which are not activities, are all gone and have become something like this. It's a nightmare and everything I wrote in past 2 days seems to have gone(because my last push was 2 days ago, I know I'm dumb). XML files are fine, and only Java files have this problem.

**Things I tried:**

1. Deleting Android Studio settings from C:\Users\PersonWhoDidntPushChanges\.AndroidStudio3.4
2. Reloading File encoding with UTF-16 and then again back to UTF-8. (Please note that only Reloading does not write the contents on disk and change the original encoding, there's a different option for that)
3. Deleting `.idea` folder from the project, and reloading the project.
4. Usual stuff, Invalidate Caches/Restart, Clean Project, Rebuilt Project.

Please also note that app ran fine and Android Studio did not give me any error until I actually opened this file, and when I saw this file in such format, I opened bunch of other classes to find those stopped working too. Any help regarding this matter would be appreciated.

I'm using

```
Android Studio 3.4.2
Build #AI-183.6156.11.34.5692245, built on June 27, 2019
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

**EDIT 1:**
Some XML files were also changed by Android Studio. The only solution that I found currently is just replacing the complete project with the one that I had on Github. Apparently some of the libraries have also changed (FloatingActionButton).

Comment: can you try the following,  1)File -> setting -> reset defaults and also invalidate cache and restart after that

Comment: @war_Hero Reset defaults might do the same thing as removing .AndroidStudio file from C:\Users\Username. Deleting .AndroidStudio basically removes everything and Android Studio is like fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just click on that activity... As in my case it is
Main3Activity
Right click and open in explorer. The open the file in notepad ++ and copy paste to again android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and after some struggle, I solved the issue so I am
sharing here so that you can also solve it.

First of all, close the android studio and then delete the AndroidStudio folder which
are stored in c derive.

Eg:- C:\Users\XXXX

Now you need to open android studio and install all the file which are asking by
Android Studio.