# Android studio all xml layout broke and now contains java code

Tags: android, android-layout

I was coding these past two weeks and it was compiling/running fine. Bear with me on the history as it might be relevant to the final issue.

One morning I start getting modules not found error and gradle warnings, out of nowhere.

I solve it then proceed to have a "Default activity not found". After I made sure I had a launcher activity in the manifest file, I figured I had a much bigger problem :

80% of my layout XML (in the /res folder) Are now containing chunks of my java code, in a completely random manner.
The icing on the cake : when I rollback to previous commit, as old as 2 weeks ago (that where running 100% fine), they also have the "broken xml java layouts"

It's one of the weirdest things that happened to me for a long time, please share anything that might give a clue.

Comment: It sounds like a source control problem rather than an Android problem. What are you using for source control?

Comment: If you check out this project on a different computer (or even a different folder), does it still exhibit this? If you *look* at your (git? subversion?) history, does it still show this?

Comment: @LarsH Bitbucket and source tree for navigation. You are right, I think I had issues with that before.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini You also suspect the versioning. I will definitely try on another computer. As for the history, it weirdly has the same .xml erroneous files (when really it shouldn't. Also I'm sure I did not gitignore those files)

Comment: When I check the project online, the xml layouts files are fine. I guess the problem is my sourcetree

Comment: At least you didn't get something like mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56996857/android-studio-file-was-loaded-in-the-wrong-encodingutf-8-and-java-file-do

Comment: Try a fresh `git clone` from the command line :)

Comment: And sure enough, a clean clone of the project worked.

I believe sourcetree and maybe android studio were at fault to some extend. Thank you all for your wise help.