# My file content was replaced with some sort of weird symbols

Tags: android, android-studio

Today, I opened the project that I have been working. I deleted .idea file and iml files due to some issues that I was facing. I reopened my project. Everything is working fine.

But if I open my some of my kotlin files or drawable files, they are looking like this. What is the problem here? I do not know if it is due to deleting those files or not.

[image]

This screentshot I took has `Reload in another encoding`. But other files does not even have this option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [File was loaded in the wrong encoding:'UTF-8' in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153703/file-was-loaded-in-the-wrong-encodingutf-8-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: @RicardoA. Unfortunately, it did not. `Reload in another encoding` is not even appearing for some files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved the issue. Everyone checked my question as dublicate. But the provided links do not solve my issue. I tried them out. No success.

**Solution 1.**

Close Android Studio. Move your project to another folder. Then, reopen your project from this new folder.

**Solution 2:**

Delete the `cache` of the Android Studio and reopen your project.